# Empty module export / require

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am working with `mongoose.js (~4.6.1)`, `node / express` and exporting a model.

When I require the model, it works in 99% of the app. However, there are a few files and directories (even some at the same level) that do not receive the proper value when I require the model, it is an empty object.

Furthermore, if I use the:

`mongoose.model.('name-of-model').find` approach, I get the error, `MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model`

I tried requiring the model into these files and wrapped a `console.log` in a setTimeout thinking it was an async issue, but the object is still empty.

Here is my problem:

- When requiring a module, it works in a few files at the same level in the directory tree, but fails to import (require) the same values in files with the same exact relative path needed to access the module. Is it possible to block requiring modules into specific files?

I also tried a few steps to see if it is a circular dependency problem after reading this [thread](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4696) but this doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: Originally, I added a few setTimeout calls to see if this was an async issue. Now when I call `mongoose.model('name-of-model').find({}).then(data => console.log(data))`, I get values and the model appears is found. However, when I directly require module, it is still empty, even after logging it in the setTimeout.

Comment: Can you please share your code on git or somewhere. @HelloWorld